# Cannot connect to Xdebug with Netbeans or DBGp Debugger.vim

Tags: php, apache, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I know this has been asked countless, as I've scoured the forums and read so many of these posts. However, it appears that the failures here are based on so many variables that the solutions are rather particular to the problem, and nothing is really remedying my problem here. I feel I need some guidance from you all more experienced players.

---

### WHAT'S HAPPENING:

**In NetBeans**:

- With my local sandbox project loaded, I click Debug Project, the index.php page opens in Chrome, the code runs all the way to the end regardless of breakpoints, and NetBeans hangs saying "Waiting For Connection (xdebug)"...

  During the above, I can see:

  > `aaron@aaron-aspire-v5:/var/log/apache2$ netstat -an | grep 9001`
  >   `tcp6       0      0 :::9001                 :::*                    LISTEN`

**In Vim**:

- I load `://localhost/html/sandbox/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug` in Chrome
- I load the same file in vim
- I press F5, and see the message `waiting for a new connection on port 9001 for 10 seconds...` so far so good.
- I reload the page in the web browser, nothing happens
- The connection times out in vim

  During the above, prior to the timeout, I can see this:

  > `aaron@aaron-aspire-v5:/var/log/apache2$ netstat -an | grep 9001`
  >   `tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:9001              0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN`

---

### WHAT I'VE GOT:

- Running Ubuntu 13.10
- Running Apache 2.4.6
- Xdebug was install via pecl
- I've edited both the /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini files and added the following:

  zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
  xdebug.default_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
  xdebug.remote_mode=rep
  xdebug.remote_host=localhost
  xdebug.remote_port=9001
  xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
- phpinfo() now returns the following regarding xdebug:

xdebug

```
xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.2.5
IDE Key => aaron  
Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $  
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100 => 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /var/log/apache2/xdebug.log => /var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => rep => rep
xdebug.remote_port => 9001 => 9001
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

- For NetBeans 7.4: Under Tools => Options => General I'm using "No Proxy"; Test Connection returns Success; Under Tools => Options => PHP => Debugging I have Debugger Port: 9001, Session ID: netbeans-xdebug, Maximum Data Length: 2048, Stop at First Line: True, all other options unchecked.
- For debugger.vim v1.0.2 (and debugger.py): both debugger.vim and debugger.py are added to my /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugins folders, `let g:debuggerPort = 9001` has been added to my .vimrc file, and `php_value xdebug.remote_port 9001` has been added to my apache2.conf file.

---

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set your `xdebug.idekey => no value`

```
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
```

also

```
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => O
```

is wrong.

Set it to

```
; idekey can be just about anything, but the value in php.ini needs
; to match the value used in the environment that launches php. 
xdebug.idekey=vim_session
```

and

```
; We have to turn on remote_autostart when running php from
; cli.  That's probably a good reason to keep the cli and apache
; versions of php.ini distinct.
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

You should see a message like `waiting for a new connection on port 9000 for 5 seconds…` at the bottom of the screen.

**You have five seconds to now refresh the PHP page.**

This will create a connection between the debugger and client. Now you’re debugging. Follow the instructions in the Help window to step into, over and out of code. Press F5 to run the code until a breakpoint (which you can set using : BP )

also look at this answer [PHP debugger for Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17885410/1322642)

**Update**

Let phpinfo run again and see if the values ​​I have mentioned are correct now? Then look also what other php config files still in use and look at the content.

Getting the server to connect on a different port is a little trickier. You need to set a custom php.ini value (xdebug.remote_port) **for each user**. It works best if you’re using VirtualHost’s in Apache. Just add the following line to **the VirtualHost section** of your httpd.conf:

```
php_value xdebug.remote_port 9001
```

Now restart Apache and if you **use that VirtualHost and that vi user**, then they should connect successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I set the idekey, although most all of the documentation I've read has simply suggested that the idekey needs to be set to 1 when running the script, perhaps in that instance it would need to be set in the php.ini accordingly? I also turned remote_autostart on, but I have no success, we're still just listening on port 9001 with no response. Also your solution doesn't solve anything for NetBeans; I think it's something a little more global as I'm having the same result with two different development environments...